# Input array sorted into even and odd numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am new to Java and stuck on the following task. We are working with arrays and are supposed to create an array with the length based on our input. No other methods than `main()` are allowed.

Then the input array will randomly select integers between 0-999 and put them in the array, then we are supposed to create a new array with the same numbers and length but sorted with even numbers first and then odd numbers.

Example:

```
How many variables do you want? 4      

Here are the random variables: 4 7 8 1   
Here are the sorted variables: 4 8 7 1   
Of your chosen variables 2 are even and 2 are odd
```

My code so far is this.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int checker;
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many variables between 0-999 you want?: ");

    int n = s.nextInt();

    int arr[] = new int[n];
    int ord[] = new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    }

    System.out.print("Here are your random numbers: ");

    for(int i : arr)
    {
        System.out.print(i + " ");  
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        checker = arr[i] % 2;

        if(checker == 0)
        {
            even = even + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            odd = odd + 1;
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Of the chosen numbers" + even + "is even and" + odd + "is odd");
}
```

Comment: I think you should say specifically what you are having trouble with, and at least make an attempt at the sorting algorithm.

Comment: Are you having trouble? Where is your problem? if you can help scope down the problem it will be much smoother

Comment: BTW you can bitwise AND the RMB with 01 to check if the variable is odd.

Comment: @TheBlueCat, why would you want to do that? IMHO `arr[i] % 2 == 0` is clearer to read (and equally efficient, but this doesn’t matter).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `arr[i]=(int)(Math.random()*100)+1;` is wrong. This will give you a number in the range of 1-100, instead of 0-999. You need to write it like this:

`arr[i]=(int)(Math.random()*1000);`

Secondly, the condition of your last for loop is `i<n-1` instead of `i<n`. That needs to be fixed too.

Now, we just need to sort the array. We are already looping through the array to count the number of even and odd numbers, so we might as well sort the array simultaneously.

Let's have two additional empty arrays, one for the even numbers and one for the odd numbers, where we store the values temporarily:

```
int[] evens = new int[n];
int[] odds = new int[n];
```

Now, every time we find an even or odd number, we can insert them into one of these arrays:

```
if(checker == 0) {
    evens[even] = arr[i]; //new line of code
    even = even + 1;
} else {
    odds[odd] = arr[i]; //new line of code
    odd = odd + 1;
}
```

Now, all we have to do is to insert the values in these two arrays, into the final array `ord`:

```
for(int i=0; i<even; i++) {
    ord[i] = evens[i];
}

for(int i=0; i<odd; i++) {
    ord[even+i] = odds[i];
}
```

And now we have the sorted array, as we wanted.

Now you can print it just the way you printed your unsorted array:

```
System.out.print("Here are the sorted variables:");
for(int i : ord) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some guys beat me to it, but i'm going to answer and give you some advice anyway.

This is the code you should add behind your last for loop.

```
    int iEven=0;     // the even part starts at the beginning
    int iOdd=even;   // the odd part starts where the even one ends
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(arr[i] % 2 == 0){
            ord[iEven] = arr[i];
            iEven++; 
        }else{
            ord[iOdd] = arr[i];
            iOdd++;
        }
    }

    System.out.print("\nHere are the sorted variables: ");
    for(int i:ord){
        System.out.print(i+" ");    
    }
```

What it does is it puts the even numbers at the beginning of the array and the ones where the even ones will end.

You should also fix your for loop: '*for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)*'.
In this case it will be running one time less than you want.
Either put *'i <= n-1'* or *'i < n'*, or the best option is to use *'i < array.length'* and it will change whenever you change the array and you needn't worry about changing it every time.

And now for advice... Writing your code like this:

> checker = arr[i] % 2;
>       if(checker == 0)

can be improved like this:

> if(arr[i] % 2 == 0)

and it looks much nicer.

Another thing that will make programming easier for you is using *i++* (or *i--*) for increasing a variable by 1. It saves a little typing. Or if you want to increase by more you use *i+=3* or *i-=7*.

Hope this helps

Comment: Good answer. However, `i` is already set to the length of the array. There is no point in writing `arr.length` instead of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to write your own comparator:
First compare if they one is even and the other one odd.  If they are you already know which one is supposed to go first, otherwise compare then naturally.

```
Integer ord[] = new Integer[n];
Arrays.asList(arr).stream().sorted(new Comparator<Integer>() {
                                       @Override
                                       public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                                           if (o1 % 2 == 0 && o2 % 2 == 1) {
                                               return -1;
                                           } else if (o1 %2 == 1 && o2 % 2 == 0) {
                                               return 1;
                                           }
                                           return o1.compareTo(o2);
                                       }
                                   }).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(ord);
```

Comment: I’d call that overcomplicating things. Also the original poster said no other method than `main()` was allowed, so I assume yout `compare()` is a nogo here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily enough by modifying your final loop. The key is to fill the array with even numbers from the front, and with odd numbers from the back. And when you're done, the `even` index tells you how many even numbers there are. Like this:

```
int even = 0;
int odd = n-1;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    checker = arr[i] % 2;

    if(checker == 0)
    {
        // even numbers fill from 0, forward
        ord[even] = arr[i];
        ++even;
    }
    else
    {
        // odd numbers fill from n-1, backward
        ord[odd] = arr[i];
        --odd;
    }
}

System.out.print("Of the chosen numbers" + even + "is even and" + (n-even) + "is odd");
```